# Having extra end in (if else) containing form in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have this partial in which i am using if elsif and form in them on certain conditions. I am getting a end tag problem because of the conditions in rendering a partial. Its saying me that i have a extra end in end.

```
  <% if (@company_detail.company_logo.blank?)%>
<h3>ADD LOGO</h3>
<% else %>
<img src="<%= "#{@company_detail.company_logo}"%>" class="logo-image" alt="logo"/>
<% end -%>
<div class="overlay align-right">

<%= form_for(:company_detail, :url => {:action => 'changeLogo', :id => @company_detail.id}, :remote => true, :html => {:multipart => true, :method => :post }) do |f| %>

<p style="display:none;">
  <input type="file" name = "logo" id="logoUploadField" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg" onChange='upload()'/>
  <button id="upload_logo" type="submit"></button>
</p>
<% end -%>  

<% if (@company_detail.company_logo.blank?) %>
<p class="align-right">
  <button class="button small green" id="add_logo" type="reset"><span>Add</span></button>
</p>
<% elsif (@company_detail.company_logo.present?)%>
<%= form_tag({:action => 'removeLogo', :id => @company_detail.id}, :remote => true, :html => {:method => :post }) %>
<p class="align-right">
  <button class="button small green" id="change_logo" type="reset"><span>Change</span></button>
  <button class="button small green" type="submit"><span>Remove</span></button>
  <% end %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not including `do` like code in second form.

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'removeLogo', :id => @company_detail.id}, :remote => true, :html => {:method => :post }) do %>
```

Comment: oh..yes...i forget to add it. thanks for pointing out for me.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the "do" in this line:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'removeLogo', :id => @company_detail.id}, :remote => true, :html => {:method => :post }) %>
```

add the "do" here:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'removeLogo', :id => @company_detail.id}, :remote => true, :html => {:method => :post }) do %>
```

and it should work.

Comment: oh..yes...i forget to add it. thanks for pointing out for me.